# Formatting rows of crystal report output

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am a new to crystal report (2008) and need help on my formatting problem.
I have output sample as below in crystal report:

```
  srNo    Name    ID    assigned_number
  ==================================
    1     aaa    111    1
    2     bbb    222    2
    3     ccc    333    3
    4     ddd    444    23
    5     fff    445    32
    6     ggg    432    1
    7     ffr    435    2
    8     rty    654    43
    9     ttt    434    33
    10    trt    343    1
    11    rre    346    2
    12    gth    543    3
    13    fgr    644    54
    14    yyy    431    2
    15    tut    323    3
    16    hyj    777    4
    17    juu    322    32
```

Have a look on last column assigned_number, here I want to highlight the row values (with row color) whenever the last column values are 1, 2, 3 consecutively (not 1, 2 or 2, 3).

So, here **srNo 1 to 3** and **10 to 12** should be highlighted with row color as the last column values are 1,2,3(consecutively).

Let me know if it's not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You right-click on the field in your assigned_number column and choose Format Field. Then in the Border tab you check the Background box and enter a conditional formula under the "x+2" icon next to Background. 
The formula is a little tricky. I have not tested this but it could go something like:

```
if previous ({assigned_number}) = 1 and
next({assigned_number}) = 3 then crRed
else crWhite
```

This will color the row with the 2 in it. Unfortunately "next" and "previous" are only limited to one record each way, so for 1 and 3 that won't work.

EDIT:

This formula will work but also highlight 1,2 and 2,3 combos. Even with a formula trying to get the previous 2 records ( the 1,2 when you're at 3) or next 2 (2,3 when you're at 1) doesn't work.

if {assigned_number} in [1, 2, 3] and
previous({assigned_number}) = 1 and
next({assigned_number}) = 3 or
{assigned_number} = 1 and
next({assigned_number}) = 2 or
{assigned_number} = 3 and
previous({assigned_number}) = 2
then crRed 
else crWhite

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the above sample that I have shown above is only for consecutive 1,2 and 3, but i have to implement the same for consecutive 1 to 6 values. I have to check for 1 to 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Right(assigned_number) in [1,2,3]
Then crred
else crwhite.
```

now you can extend this formula to the any number of values.

Comment: I got your point, but this will highlight srNo 6,7 as well as srNo 14,15 also. But in my case it should check for consecutive values of 1,2,3.... as mentioned earlier only srNo 1 to 3 and srNo 10 to 12 should be highlighted.